# Class model missing even it already created

Tags: extensions, magento2

While install develop tool of Ced i getting this problem
Magento not found class even it created .

[image]

registration.php
[image]
Manager.php

How to fix it! I have check many time config , paths, registration file

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [this](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2311) issue. There is a workaroud described. 
Also make sure to use the latest Magento 2.0.0-rc2, it might be fixed there already.